# Android static buttons tabs with options on click

Tags: android, material-design, android-tabs

Hello I want to do something like the picture below:
[image]
There you can see the "static tab" what I mean where said: "Comida, Refinar, Ordenar" This is what I want to make. I'm sure that somewhere is a theme where I can download example but I don't know where.

Then, when you click I need to open another windows like this:
[image]

How can I do something like this?
Thanks

Comment: @nukeforum Swipe tabs. But is not the same

Comment: You can also just make a bar of buttons and use Fragments to swap between "tabs"

Answer (score 0):

A TabHost would work well with that, there are a lot of tutorials to help with the set up. Very simple in comparison to making that through a custom approach, which is necessary.